# ORA-01109 Error (Database Not Open), But It's Open in SQL Plus - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

I'm getting the error "ORA-01109: database not open" in Oracle SQL Developer, in Oracle Database 19c and SQL Developer 21.2.1 Windows 64-bit.

I've gone into SQL Plus to open the database and used commands like "ALTER DATABASE OPEN;" and shut down/restart the instance to open the database. It was originally on Status "MOUNTED," but it now says Status is "OPEN" when entering the command "select instance_name, status from v$instance;" (instance_name is listed as "orcl"). However, I still get the same ORA-01109 error when opening my database, "CS4347" in Oracle SQL Developer. How can I open this database in Oracle SQL developer? This error occurs when I try to expand the database or connect to it.

Comment: If multitenant, check the status of your pluggable databases: SQL>show pdbs

Comment: @BjarteBrandt i got:
SQL> show pdbs; 
CON_ID (2, 3) / CON_NAME (PDB$SEED, ORCLPDB) / OPEN MODE (READ ONLY, MOUNTED) / RESTRICTED (NO);
Is "MOUNTED" corresponding to ORCLPDB the problem here?

Comment: please update your question and format your findings.

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle multitenant your can open the pdb and save the state:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba # to the CDB
alter pluggable database orclpdb open;
alter pluggable database orclpdb save state;
```